# How to implement drawing with mouse using QPainter + QPixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement drawing by mouse.

When I run my code and try to draw, I see no results on canvas. What's wrong with it?

Code below only contains class Canvas code and doesn't include UI and other things in my project.

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Canvas(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.white)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(p)        
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap())
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.last = None
        self.painter = QPainter(self.pixmap())
        self.painter.begin(self)        

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.last:
            self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
            self.painter.drawLine(self.last, event.pos())

            self.last = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.last = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the pixmap a size, save it as member variable, dont `pass` in the `paintEvent` and reset pixmap after drawing on it.

(Careful you are using `event.pos()` which is the position inside the `QLabel`, when you resize the `QPixmap` and `QLabel` sizes are not the same anymore and you get an offset.)

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Canvas(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.white)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.myPixmap = QPixmap(200,200)
        self.setMinimumSize(200,200)
        self.painter = QPainter(self.myPixmap)
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.black)
        self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
        self.painter.fillRect(0,0,200,200, Qt.white)
        self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)
        self.last = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.last:
            self.painter.drawLine(self.last, event.pos())

            self.last = event.pos()
            self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.last = None

    def updateSize(self, width, height):
        pm = QPixmap(width, height)
        pm.fill(Qt.white)
        old = self.myPixmap
        self.myPixmap = pm
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.black)
        self.painter = QPainter(pm)
        self.painter.drawPixmap(0,0,old)
        self.setPixmap(pm)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if event.oldSize().width() > 0:
            self.updateSize(event.size().width(), event.size().height())
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it works! I wonder how can I get this QPixmap to take all available space of parent widget(QLabel)?

Comment: @BrainlessDuck see my edit. you have to call the function `updateSize` after resizing. You can get the `Canvas` current size by its [size](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop). (I also replaced `setFixedSize` by `setMinimumSize`!)